# Interactive line plot using slider in Plotly in Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am having difficulties customising the aesthetics of an interactive line plot in Plotly Python, and would appreciate some assistance from members of the community here.

Here is a picture of the plot I would like to amend, a working example of which is supplied further down the page:

[image]

In particular, I want to know how or what can be modified so that I can

1. Remove 'step-#' in 'Sample size n = step-#', and replace with 'Sample size n = #', where `#` is a number. Currently the value of `#` is also out of sync with the title. So in this figure `#` should be displayed as 300.

2. Remove the 'step-#' annotating the slider, and replace it with something else.

3. Adjust number of 'ticks' on the slider line.

Ideally, I would appreciate if someone could tell me definitively what keywords or parameters I need to be amending in Plotly.

Having read the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/sliders/), it is not clear to me what parameters/keyword arguments I need to be tweaking in order to customise the aesthetics to be closer to what I desire. And I don't know if the customisation I'm looking for can be achieved with these parameter/keyword argument tweaks, or if it would require a rewriting of the code I have reproduced below.

Essentially, I want *the slider* looking something more like the one in this example:

[image]

---

**Minimal working code example.**

I adapted this code from the example from the Plotly documentation on sliders [here](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#reference)

```
# MWE for SO upload.

# Import modules.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

# Risk under squared error loss of the Hodges-Le Cam estimator.
def risk_hodges_estimator(theta, sample_size):
    n = sample_size
    w1 = ((n ** 0.25) + theta * np.sqrt(n)) / np.sqrt(2)
    w2 = ((n ** 0.25) - theta * np.sqrt(n)) / np.sqrt(2)

    risk = ((n * (theta ** 2))
            + (w1 / np.sqrt(np.pi)) * np.exp(-(w1 ** 2))
            + ((1 - n * (theta ** 2)) * norm.cdf(-w1 * np.sqrt(2)))
            + (w2 / np.sqrt(np.pi)) * np.exp(-(w2 ** 2))
            + ((1 - n * (theta ** 2)) * norm.cdf(-w2 * np.sqrt(2))))

    return risk

theta_range = np.linspace(-2, 2, num=1000)

# Initialise graph object.
fig = go.Figure()

# Add 'traces' for each slider step, which in my case, means that each trace is a risk function.
for step in range(0,500,10):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="royalblue", width=1),
            x=theta_range,
            y=risk_hodges_estimator(theta_range, step)))

# Set which trace or curve you want to be visible prior to the visualisation from being activated.
fig.data[1].visible = True

# Create and add slider.
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method='update',
        args=[{'visible': [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {'title': 'Risk function of the Hodges-Le Cam estimator, rescaled by sample size n = ' + str((i + 1)* 10) + '.'}],
    )
    step['args'][0]['visible'][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

# 'active' kwarg sets value of slider to start at.
sliders = [dict(
    active=1,
    currentvalue={'prefix': 'Sample size n = '},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]
fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    xaxis_title=r'$\theta$',
    yaxis_title=r'$n \cdot R_n(\tilde{\theta}_n, \theta)$'
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **plotly** examples are quite often portable code (easily refactored to R, JS or python)
- structure code in more pythonic way and it becomes obvious how to achieve what you want

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="royalblue", width=1),
            x=theta_range,
            y=risk_hodges_estimator(theta_range, n),
        )
        for n in range(0, 500, 10)
    ],
)

fig = fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=r'$\theta$',
    yaxis_title=r'$n \cdot R_n(\tilde{\theta}_n, \theta)$',
    sliders=[
        {
            "active": 1,
            "currentvalue": {"prefix": "Sample size n = "},
            "steps": [
                {
                    "label": n,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": [v == n for v in range(0, 500, 10)]},
                        {
                            "title": f"Risk function of the Hodges-Le Cam estimator, rescaled by sample size n = {n}"
                        },
                    ],
                }
                for n in range(0, 500, 10)
            ],
        }
    ],
)

# pick up defaults from what has already been setup
fig.data[1].visible = True
fig.layout.title = fig.layout.sliders[0]["steps"][1]["args"][1]["title"]
fig
```